# Monaco: Illegal value for lineNumber

Tags: monaco-editor

I am dynamically changing the content of my monaco editor.
When I have error line marked, I now get an error if the new code is shorter (I recently updated to 0.38 from. 0.30).

I attach decorations with

```
this.decorations = this.editor!.deltaDecorations(this.decorations, newDecorations);
// this.decorations = this.editor!.createDecorationsCollection(newDecorations);
```

I am calling

```
this.decorations = this.editor!.deltaDecorations(this.decorations, []);
// this.decorations = this.editor!.createDecorationsCollection([]);
```

before changing the content, but I still get an error

```
rors.js:15 Uncaught Error: Illegal value for lineNumber

Error: Illegal value for lineNumber
    at TextModel2.getLineMaxColumn (textModel.js:549:19)
    at IdentityModelLineProjection.getViewLineMaxColumn (modelLineProjection.js:232:22)
    at ViewModelLinesFromProjectedModel.getViewLineMaxColumn (viewModelLines.js:519:68)
    at ViewModel.getLineMaxColumn (viewModelImpl.js:550:28)
    at new ViewportData (viewLinesViewportData.js:18:166)
    at View._actualRender (view.js:280:30)
    at view.js:257:36
    at safeInvokeNoArg (view.js:402:16)
    at View._renderNow (view.js:257:9)
    at View._flushAccumulatedAndRenderNow (view.js:146:14)
```

What is the correct way to add/remove decorations in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody stumbling upon this, it seems like this is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3920) with Monaco 0.38. Upgrading to 0.39 fixed it for me.